# Bitcoin Core full node download crashes all the time

Tags: bitcoin-core, full-node

I'm downloading the full blockchain for the first time, and have only got a couple of laptops with i5 and 8gb ram and a couple of external hdds. The download has run for a long time on one of the hdds (five nights), the other one I started yesterday. The first have reached 58% the other 61% (in one day). The other one, I realized, were downloading it to the internal ssd, so I had to move it because is ditn't have more space. After I moved the download to the hdd it's moving as slow as the original one and at a speed that won't get finished because of continual crashing.

I'm considering continuing the download to an extarnal ssd of 250gb and then copying it over to the 500gb hdd and trying to do the last part on that, but when on hdd it crashes all the time, so I haven't got very high hopes.

Does anyone have any suggestions for me? Is the only bottleneck the hdds or can it be someplace else?

Would it be possible to download the second half only to the internal ssd and them combine them on the hdd somehow?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "crashing"? What hardware is this (CPU, RAM), what operating system?

Comment: The "first" one is a Macbook Pro, the "other" is a Huawei something with Windows. Both i5 and 8gb ram, as specified. To clarify: I've tried downloading on through my Macbook to a hdd with apfs for several days, then when visiting home I tried my brothers Huawei to a hdd with exFat.

On the Macbook the application has increasingly crashed (not responding) and this happened with the Huawei too, when I copied it to the hdd and continued the download to that location.